# How to run ggvis function on remote dplyr tbl?

Tags: r, shiny, dplyr, ggvis

My apologies if this is not a reproducible example but I am not aware of any public db I could use for it (please comment if you have any suggestions and I'll edit the question).

I have a shiny app that calls to a db (`Database: mysql 5.6.27-log`), and then plots using ggvis. I am using the following pkgs version:

```
[1] ggvis_0.4.3   dplyr_0.5.0   RMySQL_0.10.9 DBI_0.5
```

What I have is a bunch of reactive tbls that need a `collect()` before going into a ggvis function. I thought `compute()` could work as well and would have made the app faster, but I can't get ggvis to inherit what is coming from a dplyr query.

For example something like:

```
tbl(con, 'graduation') %>% 
  select(first, second) %>%
  compute() %>% 
  ggvis(~first, ~second)
```

Gives me this error message

> Error in UseMethod("prop_type") : 
>     no applicable method for 'prop_type' applied to an object of class "c('tbl_mysql', 'tbl_sql', 'tbl_lazy', 'tbl')"`

So the question would be how can I pass remote tables to ggvis; but besides that, I would like a feedback on whether what I am trying to do makes sense at all and could in fact speed up the application.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but it seems that the problem is that `ggvis` is expecting a data frame as input but you are providing something different, `ggvis` tries to interpret it as a plot property. You could try to create an extra variable with the correct format to `ggvis.`

Comment: @Geovany in the documentation it's written "a data object", which sounds more inclusive than a class `data.frame` but that's my guess. Converting to `data.frame` works but then the object is stored locally.